# How far up a limb can a severed artery retract?

Tags: hematology

This is about the application of tourniquets. I was taught a hand width above wound, but recently I read severd arteries can in some cases retract higher than that which would then bleed into the arm.

Doesn't matter if cut or tear, and if the limb is torn off or just the artery cut through, but on arms and legs, how far up can it retract?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology! You may consider posting this question to SE Medical Sciences instead (https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/), where it would be more appropriate and you will likely get better answers.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. I’m voting to close this question because it seems more appropriate for [MedicalSciences.SE] (please don't repost — instead request migration). Thanks! 